# How to create a date drawable like google calendar app

Tags: android

[image]

I don't know how to create a drawable and add it to toolbar like the image above (red circle). The number is corresponding to today's date.

If you have any ideas, please help me.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your ideas. This what I come up with:

1. Create my custom Drawable (eg: TextDrawable extends Drawable)
2. Override the draw(Canvas canvas) method
3. Programmatically add my custom Drawable to my Toolbar:

inside: onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
menu.add(0, 0, 1, getString(R.string.jump_to_today)).setIcon(new TextDrawable("22")).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

For now, it's display a text date like I want (haven't has the calendar background). I think I will have to write it on my draw method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you need to create a custom `Drawable` class and override its `draw` method

Comment: sure you have to do it in your `draw` method

Answer (score 2):

Trying writing text on an image...

Firstly, you need a calendar image without text ("22" in this case). Then, you write text "22" on the image. Something like this:

```
Bitmap calendarBitmap = ... // Load your calendar image here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(10); 
canvas.drawText("22", x, y, paint);
```

Which **x**, **y** are the coordinates of the text's position on the image. You also need to change **Color.BLACK** to the image's color for consistency.

Finally, you get calendarBitmap as a result.

Comment: After that, how do I add it to my toolbar? For now, I'm adding from res/menu.

Comment: If you're using action bar, you could get the MenuItem and update its drawable. In case it's an image, just set calendarBitmap as its bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to get the image you want as the calendar (maybe you can find it inside android resources). Then transform it into a nine patch and use it as the background drawable of your TextView.

You can read google [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) about creating nine patch. You will be able to define in wich region the text should be by defining the content area.

Comment: I think about it too, but I stuck at how do I add it to the toolbar? I'm now using res/menu to add item to Toolbar.

Comment: I forgot you want to add it to tool bar, my bad. I can think of one solution that may work (but i have not test it). Create an xml file for the icon with just a `TextView` with the drawable as background. Then when creating the menu, inflate this view and set the text. Then call `setActionView` on the menu item to set the view. The other solution that will work but is horrible is to have 31 icons (one for each day) and call `setIcon` with the appropriate one when inflating the menu. Please tell me if the first one work so i can update my answer.